# How does one plot the ratio of of a categorical column in a long form data set?

Tags: python-3.x, altair

I have a long form data set with a column `type` and `date`. `type` has two categories `gold` and`silver`. I'd like to plot the ratio of the two by date. To do that a series of transformations have to happen.  They look like this in `pandas`

```
mock_df = df.groupby(["date"])["type"].value_counts().unstack()
mock_df["gs_ratio"] = mock_df["gold"]/mock_df["silver"]
mock_df
```

[image]

Data

```
import pandas

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
    {"date": "2020-04-20", "type": "gold"},
    {"date": "2020-04-20", "type": "silver"},
    {"date": "2020-04-20", "type": "silver"},
    {"date": "2020-04-21", "type": "gold"},
    {"date": "2020-04-21", "type": "gold"},
    {"date": "2020-04-21", "type": "silver"},
    {"date": "2020-04-22", "type": "gold"},
    {"date": "2020-04-22", "type": "silver"},
    {"date": "2020-04-22", "type": "silver"},
    {"date": "2020-04-22", "type": "silver"}
])

df
```

[image]

Code tried:

```
alt.Chart(df).transform_joinaggregate(
    gs_count='count(type)',
    groupby=["date:T"]
).transform_pivot(
    'type',
    groupby=['date:T'],
    value='gs_count'
).transform_calculate(
    gs_ratio="datum.gold/datum.silver"
).mark_line().encode(
    x='date:T',
    y="gs_ratio:Q"
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues in your approach:

- you can't use type shorthands in transforms. So you should be using the actual name of the column,`"date"` rather than `"date:T"`
- `count(type)` is not equivalent to `df.type.value_counts()`. What you should do is use `count()` grouped by `type`.
- use `transform_aggregate` rather than `transform_joinaggregate`

Putting this together:

```
alt.Chart(df).transform_aggregate(
    gs_count='count()',
    groupby=["date", "type"]
).transform_pivot(
    'type',
    groupby=['date'],
    value='gs_count'
).transform_calculate(
    gs_ratio="datum.gold/datum.silver"
).mark_line().encode(
    x='date:T',
    y="gs_ratio:Q"
)
```

[image]